# Reference Request: Machine Learning from Scratch

Tags: reference-request, computer-science, book-recommendation, machine-learning

I have a background in Software Engineering and the question is a bit related to CS theory, but I find it more appropriate to post my question here.

I want to get started on Machine Learning but haven't found a book that explains the process from scratch. It is either tutorials on how to use TensorFlow (but without actually *learning* the concepts and math involved) or more rigorous books oriented towards mathematicians (another question has been asked but with a much more rigurous approach [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205684/mathematical-introduction-to-machine-learning))

One of my favorite books is [*Code: The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735611319) which explains the very basics of computer science, binary and architecture in a very intuitive and approachable fashion that can be easily understood even by people with no background in the subject.

Although not **that** deep, I have been looking for a similar resource for Machine Learning, that walks the reader through basic calculus, statistics and linear algebra and builds up to basic machine learning. More than looking for proofs, I am interested in the math behind to aid my learning.

Comment: Does this belong to Math.SE?

Comment: I liked Goodfellow-Bengio-Courville's deep learning book: https://www.deeplearningbook.org/

Comment: @QiaochuYuan nice book, also very complete and straightforward. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a basic overview you could try The Hundred Page Machine Learning Book by Burkov

If you want something a bit more substantial I would suggest An Introduction to Statistical Learning by James, Witten et al. I think it is aimed at a undergraduate audience from a variety of fields. For a even more mathematical text of the same topics then try Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie and Tibshirani, which is a classic.

Other texts that are common in the field are Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop and Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective by Murphy. Both are very readable

Comment: If I may ask, do you think that ESL is getting out of date at all? I am interested in learning about machine learning but don't have any specific goals. I am planning to read Foundations of Machine Learning by Mohri and Neural Networks and Deep Learning by Aggarwal. Both those books were published or at least updated in 2018, I think. If ESL is still fundamental then maybe I should make time for it as well.

Comment: ESL isn't going to go out of date. Other books say on things like DL may not cover the most current techniques in few years time

Comment: Okay, so ESL is not cutting-edge, but it's still foundational? I guess I should make time for it then.

Comment: yes it needs to be read

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in "Deep learning book" by Ian Goodfellow.

It starts with a bit of linear algebra and statistics(not calculus) applied to optimization problems and a general overview of machine learning followed by a deeper dive into different types of deep neural networks(feedforward, convolutional, etc.).

It's not general machine learning though, but it can be used as a starting point.