# Proof of the PAC generalization error bound using VC dimension

Tags: reference-request, computer-science, machine-learning

There is a theorem in PAC ("Probably Approximately Correct" model, in computational learning theory) that reads as follows:

> To guarantee that any hypothesis that perfectly fits the training data is probably (with probability $1-\delta$) approximately correct (with generalization error $\varepsilon$) we need to collect at least:
>   $$m \geq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left(4 \log_2\frac{2}{\delta}+8 \operatorname{VC}(H)\log_2 \frac{13}{\varepsilon} \right)$$
>    where $m$ is the number of training examples and $\operatorname{VC}(H)$ is the Vapnik—Chervonenkis dimension.

I was not able to find a place where the proof of this theorem is presented and explained. Please may somebody point me to such a place, or provide here an sketch of the proof?

Answer (score 1):

This is proven for instance in *[An Introduction to Computational Learning Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262111934)*, by M. Kearns and U. Vazirani (MIT Press, 1994).
Up to the exact constants, what you ask seems to be covered by Theorem 3.3, in Chapter 3, which states that to learn a concept class $\mathcal{C}$ a consistent hypothesis will work with this many samples:
$$
O\!\left(\frac{d}{\varepsilon}\log\frac{1}{\varepsilon}+\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\log\frac{1}{\delta}\right)
$$
where $d$ is the VC dimension of $\mathcal{C}$. A lower bound of $\Omega(\frac{d}{\varepsilon})$ is shown in Theorem 3.5. (Note that there is still a logarithmic gap between upper and lower bound.)

Since you use $\mathcal{H}$ in your question, I suppose you are also interested in the case where the algorithm uses a hypothesis (representation) class $\mathcal{H}$ to learn the concept class $\mathcal{C}$. In this case, this is Theorem 3.4 of the same chapter, with the same expression for the suficient sample complexity (but with $d$ being the VC dimension of $\mathcal{H}$, not $\mathcal{C}$).

The tight sample complexity bound seems to have been resolved recently by S. Hanneke, in *"The Optimal Sample Complexity of PAC Learning,"* 2015. ([abs/1507.00473](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.00473)). This establishes that the sample complexity of PAC-learning a concept class $\mathcal{C}$ to error $\varepsilon$ with failure probability at most $\delta$ is
$$
\Theta\!\left(\frac{d}{\varepsilon}+\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\log\frac{1}{\delta}\right)
$$
where $d = \operatorname{VC}(\mathcal{C})$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Will try to get the book, although it may take me some time (and money). I have just downloaded the article.

Comment: If you have access to a university library, either it'll be there or you could find a pdf version on the library online repository.